# Detecting proxy or VPN user in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to be showing if the user request is using a VPN proxy or not in Django. I want if a user is using a VPN it shows this "Network Error: Not Connected" and if a user is not on VPN it shows this "Network Active: Connected". I have tried looking for the answers on the internet but nothing is working. Here is my views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

import os
import platform
def check_ping():
   hostname = "xyz.com" #hostname will be..Name under: "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" when you type "ipconfig" in cmd..
   response = os.system("ping " + ("-n 1 " if  platform.system().lower()=="windows" else "-c 1 ") + hostname)
   # and then check the response...
   if response == 0:
       pingstatus = "Network Active: Connected"
   else:
       pingstatus = "Network Error: Not Connected"

   return pingstatus
response = check_ping()
#print(response)

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return JsonResponse({'status':response})
```